# почему я не могу добавить исключения в гитигнор?

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitignore, git-bash

Переношу проект который писали до меня...всё как обычно
git clone, git remote и т.д.
**Суть:** у меня файлы гитигнора на каждом уровне директорий и мне не хочется это менять, но в одной и директорий я пишу чтобы гит не трогал папку, а он берёт и всё равно пихает её в игнор :\ Подскажите что делать пожалуйста[image: один из файлов .gitignore который не работает как надо]

А вот репозиторий после пуша с этим гитигнором[image: картинка папки на которую воздействует гитигнор и там нет файлов которые добавлены в исключения]
P.S. Я не очень силён в гите( Может там можно почистить как-то память гиту и попробовать снова или ещё что

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, интересный попался вопрос. Я не сразу сообразил, но путём экспериментов понял, как это сделать.

Смотрите.

Итак, Вы хотите, чтобы начиная с папки `storage/app/public` все папки, кроме `storage/app/public/files` игнорировались. А папка `storage/app/public/files` ложилась в git вместе со всем содержимым.

при этом "Восклицательный знак(!) в начале строки означает инвертирование правила, необходим для указания исключений из правил игнорирования".

Для этого Вы пишете такой .gitignore (лежащий в storage/app/public):

```
    *
    !files/
    !.gitignore
```

И это не работает.

Как я понял путём экспериментов, для .gitignore, лежащего в storage/app/public этот путь (storage/app/public) является "корневым".

И правильный .gitignore, который будет работать так,к ак Вы хотите, должен выглядеть так:

```
    /*
    !/files/
    !.gitignore
```

Видите, в первых двух строчках добавилось по косой черте вначале имени.

Я проверил - ( https://github.com/junecat/TestGitForSOquestion/ ) - работает!

**Дополнение от автора вопроса**
Проблема была решена. Не знаю почему так, но я добавил в каждую папку (которая не должна была улетать в игнор) файл .gitignore и прописал:

```
!файлИлиПапкаКотораяНеИдётВИгнор
!.gitignore
```

И в моём случае в родительской папке на всякий случай оставил:

```
*
!files/
!.gitignore
```

Так и была решена проблема.

Comment: Подождите
А разве добавление восклицательного знака не является наказом не трогать эту папку?
Если нет, то подскажите пожалуйста как сказать гиту чтобы он её не трогал?
P.S. Просто у меня там стоит *, но папку files надо уберечь, ибо там картинки сайта

Comment: @ВладиславГривенко - спасибо, я как раз это заметил и переписывал ответ, когда Вы оставили комментарий! - А, всё, я понял вопрос... я просто не въехал в то, хотите вы исключить эту папку из гита, или наоборот, хотите её включить. Сейчас попробую промоделировать ситуацию

Comment: хорошо, спасибо) Если получится, то будет очень круто!)

Comment: я попробовал и вроде получилось. Исправил ответ. Пробуйте!

Comment: к сожалению так и не вышло решить проблему

Comment: А Вы прочитали мой исправленный ответ? Исправили .gitignore? Можно сделать так: попробуйте снова проделать всё то же самое, но сразу написать .gitignore так, как я посоветовал?

Comment: возможно в том что это не основной гитигнор или ещё в чём...даже не знаю :с     
Попробовал как вы сказали не получилось. Может я уже наломал чего, попробую сейчас удалить и заново склонировать и вдруг поможет)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130003/discussion-between---and-s-h).